# Why does Cypress test in GUI(cypress open) pass but fails in command line(cypress run) even though I using chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing a test for 4 endpoints and I can see it's successfully completed when trying with cypress open command. However, If I try to run cypress run command, I see a timeout issue. Is there any difference between these 2 commands ?

Comment: could you add the commands yo uare running

Comment: I'm trying to run using below command: 

``
1) ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
2) ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run

``
First one passes and second fails. Also I'm trying to read the values from cypress.env.json file.

Comment: is the report shows as test was ran in same browser ?

Comment: I can see it's running in chrome browser. But I couldn't understand why its failing in command line.

Comment: when running in command line its running headless in differen browser ?

Comment: by default run runs in electron headless

Comment: headless browsers are faster than normal browsers so you might have to handle waits as elements appears and change faster

Comment: else specify browser and non headless explicitly with run command

Answer (score 0):

Try running below commands:

```
cypress run -C <path to your config  file>
```

and

```
cypress open -C <path to your config  file>
```

In the config mention the browser else it will run in electron browser

See in your report if the test are run in same browser else pass --browser explicitly for both the commands

Comment: My cypress.env.json file is in main folder. so how do I run it ?

Comment: @Seeker provite the absolute path to the config file

Comment: I can still see the timeout issue running with the cypress run command.